# Kusto - rendering columnchart does not honor data row order

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

I have following data and I am rendering columnchart with it but columnchart does not create graphs in the same order as data i.e. first column as July then August and then so on.

Can someone help me here on how to ensure order in columnchart

```
datatable (Month: string, total_core_hours: long) [
    "July",long(2000000),
    "August",long(3361305),
    "September",long(2478058),
    "October",long(2869816),
    "November",long(1663719),
    "December",long(5039456),
    "January",long(22773168),
    "February",long(10974652),
    "March",long(27346583),
]
| project Month, total_core_hours
| render columnchart
```

[image]

Comment: (1) Data set does not have a "natural" order. There is no reason you'll get it ordered if you didn't sort it. (2) Is that your real data? No dates, only months names?

Comment: I thought because datatable is a list it would honor order but that is not the case. I was able to bring natural order by using datetime instead of string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following worked for me, by converting string to datetime which brings natural order to data:

```
datatable (StartDate: datetime , total_core_hours: long) [
    datetime(2021-10-01),long(2869816),
    datetime(2021-11-01),long(1663719),
    datetime(2021-12-01),long(5039456),
    datetime(2022-01-01),long(22773168),
    datetime(2022-02-01),long(10974652),
    datetime(2022-03-01),long(27346583),
]
| extend formattedStartDate = format_datetime(StartDate, "yyyy-MM")
| project formattedStartDate, total_core_hours
| render columnchart
```

[image]